# Алгоритм Евклида проблемы с синтаксисом bash

Tags: linux, bash

Только начал работать с bash и синтаксис очень непонятен. В чем мои ошибки?

```
#!/bin/bash
function_Euclids() {
while [ $1 -ne 0 ] && [ $2 -ne 0 ] 
    do
            if [[ $1 -gt $2 ]]  
                    then
                            let $1+=$1/$2
                    else    let $2+=$2/$1
            fi
    done    
    let a=$1+$2 
    echo" $a"  
                    }

function_Euclids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, при вызове функции `function_Euclids` вы забыли передать ей аргументы.

Во вторых, не надо ничего присваивать аргументам. Заведите пару локальных переменных, присвойте им значения аргументов и работайте с ними. Т.е. как-то так:

```
p1=$1
p2=$2
while [ $p1 -ne 0 ] && [ $p2 -ne 0 ] 
do
   ....
```

В третьих, выражение для `let` должно быть строкой (кстати, имена переменных в ней можно использовать без `$` (разыменования)). Вот в таком духе:

```
let a="p1 + p2"
```

- (конечно, без пробелов можно написать так: `let a=p1+p2` (или `let a=$p1+$p2`, тут строка для вычисления образуется в результате текстовой подстановки), но без них код выглядит не слишком привлекательно).

И наконец, в четвертых -- в алгоритме Евклида вычисляются не частные, а **остатки** (и они не добавляются, а замещают прошлые значения `p1` и `p2`). Т.е. надо вот так:

```
let p1="p1 % p2"
```

вместо `let $1+=$1/$2`

В результате получаем

```
#!/bin/bash


function_Euclids() {
    p1=$1
    p2=$2
    while [ $p1 -ne 0 ] && [ $p2 -ne 0 ] 
    do
        if [[ $p1 -gt $p2 ]]  
        then
            let p1="p1 % p2"
        else
            let p2="p2 % p1"
        fi
    done    
    let a="p1+p2"
    echo "a = $a"  
}

function_Euclids $1 $2
```

По хорошему, надо бы еще проверить `$1` и `$2` перед вызовом функции, но это уж вы как-нибудь сами потренируйтесь.